# Does the word "spectrum" in linear algebra have different meanings?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

I'm reading several papers that refer to the spectrum as the set of all possible eigenvalues of a matrix, i.e., counting multiplicity, so that a list such as $\sigma = (\alpha_1, ... \alpha_n, 0, 0, 0,...,0)$ can be the spectrum of some matrix.

But I had learned in my linear algebra courses that the spectrum is the set of *distinct* eigenvalues.

Who is right?

Does the spectrum have different meanings?

This difference is not a triviality, for the paper that I am trying to work on - for example, adding more zeroes to the list changes the problem; adding more zeroes can increase the solvability of the problem.

So, I just want to make sure.

Thanks,

Comment: Usually it is the *set* of eigenvalues and no list. But each author can define notions as he/she wishes, right?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp, right.  Unfortunately, the author at the beginning of this  paper also writes a list using set notation, e.g., he writes "find conditions in which the list $\sigma = \{\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n\}$... "

Comment: Just wary of this paper, but the ideas in the paper are consistent with other papers @FriedrichPhilipp.  But I think list notation needs to be used and also the word "spectrum" should not be used ...

Comment: Yes, the word means different things in different contexts. It doesn't even mean "eigenvalues" in functional analysis: the spectrum of a linear operator on a function space is often strictly larger than the set of its eigenvalues. Just pay close attention to whatever definitions are given.

Comment: Ah, interesting.  Ok, will do -- thanks so much for your help @symplectomorphic :-)

Answer (score -1):

Spectrum is a subject in functional analysis rather than linear algebra.
Its concept in functional analysis is more extended than eigenvalue.
Eigenvalue is a special case of elements of spectrum. You can see functional analysis Rudin.

Comment: This should've been a comment.